# If you click the left mouse button on the "TextBox", the element is accelerated

Tags: c#, wpf

Actions to see the problem:

1. Create a WPF project (I'm using .NET 7)
2. Insert the code below

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,240,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Height="97"/>
        <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,240,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="97" Width="160" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Border Name="MyBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="96,45,0,0" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="131" Width="76"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 96; i <= 300; i++)
            {
                MyBorder.Margin = new Thickness(i,45,0,0);
                await Task.Delay(5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3) Click on the Start button, point at the TextBox and press the left mouse button and see that Border started to move faster.**

**Why does it happen? How to fix this problem?**

Video of the problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KWsp-ghJMnntW9KqbxcHxjtQ_fQ2tTbo/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 2):

Trying to replicate this problem didn't work. I did notice that you are missing a "using System.Threading.Tasks" and that the border glitches when clicking the button multiple times though. I'd advise to disable the button before the for loop and enable it after the for loop is done again like this:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,240,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Height="97"/>
    <Button Name="start_button" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,240,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="97" Width="160" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Border Name="MyBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="96,45,0,0" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="131" Width="76"/>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            start_button.IsEnabled = false;
            for (int i = 96; i <= 300; i++)
            {
                MyBorder.Margin = new Thickness(i,45,0,0);
                await Task.Delay(5);
            }
            start_button.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you could provide some more info on what windows version you are using and if you changed any other files in your project. (Maybe try to just recreate the project and see if that changes something)

Proof that it works for me:

-Task.Delay(5):

[image]

-Task.Delay(10):

[image]

Comment: I'm using Windows 11. The project is brand new, no other files have been edited. I run the project in Debug and Release and the situation is the same.

Comment: I ran the programme on a Windows 10 virtual machine and the same problem there

Comment: @MaKeSter you use the same windows version as me so that cant be the problem and if you didnt edit any other files i really dont know what could cause this. You are probably better of using some alternative solution like [EldHasp's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77341136/22780906)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using animation.
This will give a much smoother movement.

```xml
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,240,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Height="97"/>
        <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,240,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="97" Width="160" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Border Name="MyBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
                Margin="96,45,0,0" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="131" Width="76" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="brdMove" X="0"/>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

```cs
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            btn.IsEnabled = false;
            DoubleAnimation animation = new(200, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
            animation.Completed += delegate { btn.IsEnabled = true; };
            brdMove.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animation);
        }
```